# How to Simplify expression into partial Trignometric form?

Tags: algebra

I have an expression with thousands of terms each of them has the form
(1- Exp[-2 a x]) . I want to be able to write it as
2  Exp[-  a x]  Sinh[ a x] . How do I do this without doing
it for each term separately and that too - by hand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try  rule `Exp[- 2 z_] -> 1 - 2 Exp[-z ] Sinh[z ]`

```
1 - Exp[-2 a x] /. Exp[- 2 z_] -> 1 - 2 Exp[-z ] Sinh[z ]
(*2 E^(-a x) Sinh[a x]*)
```